# How to position the element at the same position as another element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

After Clicking Hello button I was the new hello button to be displayed at exactly the same position as the previous one was there how can I do that ?

```js
  const rightDiv = document.querySelector('#rightDiv');
  const leftButton = document.querySelector('#leftButton');


  function myFunction() {
    rightDiv.style.display = "none";
    leftButton.style.display = "block";  }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">

  <div class="col" style="height: 9vh; border: 1px solid black; width: 100%">
    <button id="leftButton" style="display: none"> Hello</button>

  </div>

  <div id="rightDiv" class="col" style="height: 9vh; border: 1px solid black">
    <button onclick="myFunction()"> Hello</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

**Edit:** I want to set the position same as the other button so that I looks like the button never moved

Comment: You could just give them exactly same styles... with only difference of 'display' property.

Comment: This seems a bit of a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). While replacing a button with another is totally doable, you should never have to do it. You can use simple JavaScript logic to change what happens when you first click the button with something else. Instead of having two buttons you have one button which does different things on first click and on subsequent ones.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu yes thats true but I am using a side nav https://stackblitz.com/angular/vkgodbqqjaae So I need to hide the button and show another its part of UX design

Answer (score -1):

If `none` is specified for the `display` property, **no box is generated**. Also, `offsetWidth`, `offsetHeight` attributes, etc. return `0` if there is no CSS layout box associated with the element<sup>[[1]](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view-1/#dom-htmlelement-offsetwidth)</sup>.

> ### 9.2.4 The 'display' property<sup>[[2]](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#propdef-display)</sup>
>
> This value causes an element to not appear in the formatting structure (i.e., in visual media the element generates no boxes and has no effect on layout). Descendant elements do not generate any boxes either; the element and its content are removed from the formatting structure entirely. This behavior cannot be overridden by setting the `display` property on the descendants.
>
> Please note that a display of 'none' does not create an invisible box; it creates no box at all. CSS includes mechanisms that enable an element to generate boxes in the formatting structure that affect formatting but are not visible themselves. Please consult the section on visibility for details.

Therefore, use the `visibility` property instead of the `display` property. The `visibility` property can be used to make the box generated by the element invisible and affect the layout.

> ### 11.2 Visibility: the 'visibility' property<sup>[[3]](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visufx.html#propdef-visibility)</sup>
>
> The `visibility` property specifies whether the boxes generated by an element are rendered. Invisible boxes still affect layout (set the `display` property to 'none' to suppress box generation altogether). Values have the following meanings:
>
> - **hidden**
>     The generated box is invisible (fully transparent, nothing is drawn), but still affects layout. Furthermore, descendants of the element will be visible if they have 'visibility: visible'.

Bootstrap 4 uses Flexbox for grid layout, so you can use the `order` property to control the order of flex items<sup>[[4]](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/)</sup>.

> ## Grid system<sup>[[4]](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/)</sup>
>
> Bootstrap’s grid system uses a series of containers, rows, and columns to layout and align content. It’s built with flexbox and is fully responsive. Below is an example and an in-depth look at how the grid comes together.

From the above, you can do this using the `visibility` and `order` properties:

```js
const rightDiv = document.querySelector('#rightDiv');
const leftButton = document.querySelector('#leftButton');


function myFunction() {
  rightDiv.style.visibility = "hidden";
  leftButton.style.visibility = "visible";
  leftButton.parentElement.style.order = 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">

  <div class="col" style="height: 9vh; border: 1px solid black; width: 100%">
    <button id="leftButton" style="visibility: hidden"> Hello</button>

  </div>

  <div id="rightDiv" class="col" style="height: 9vh; border: 1px solid black">
    <button onclick="myFunction()"> Hello</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

---

If you want the `#leftButton` width to be `100%`, you can do this using a pseudo-element and the `align-items` property.

```js
const rightDiv = document.querySelector('#rightDiv');
const leftButton = document.querySelector('#leftButton');


function myFunction() {
  rightDiv.style.display = "none";
  leftButton.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
/* Position adjustment by pseudo-elements and `margin` for` padding` etc ... */

.leftColumn::before {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  content: "";
}

#leftButton {
  margin: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">

  <div class="col d-flex align-items-start leftColumn" style="height: 9vh; border: 1px solid black; width: 100%"> <!-- Use flexbox -->
    <button id="leftButton" style="display: none"> Hello</button>
  </div>

  <div id="rightDiv" class="col" style="height: 9vh; border: 1px solid black">
    <button onclick="myFunction()"> Hello</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

---

Reference:

1. [CSSOM View Module](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view-1/)
2. [Cascading Style Sheets Level 2 Revision 2 (CSS 2.2) Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/)

Comment: Thanks but `visibility` is not what I am looking for I need to move position as the div will grow and shrink https://stackblitz.com/angular/vkgodbqqjaae